# Трудный случай пунктуации

Tags: пунктуация

Несмотря на то что наследственность играет огромную роль, тем не менее сохранение здоровья позвоночника начинаеся со школьного возраста.

Answer (score 2):

Но стиль! Зачем там "тем не менее", если уже есть "несмотря на то что"?

Что значит "сохранение здоровья начинается"? Само, что ли, начинается? Неряшливо.

И логика страдает... Из того, что наследственность играет роль, следует, что здоровье сохранять нужно со школьного возраста?

В общем, кашшшмар.

Answer (score 1):

Несмотря на то что наследственность играет огромную роль, тем не менее сохранение здоровья позвоночника начинается со школьного возраста.

Всё верно, больше знаков препинания нет.

Сложный подчинительный союз НЕСМОТРЯ НА ТО ЧТО не расчленяется, т.к. придаточное предложение предшествует главному. Тем не менее - не вводное слово, а союз (=НО), тоже не выделяется запятыми.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаемый вариант для выражения данной мысли: "Несмотря на то что наследственность играет огромную роль, о сохранении здоровья позвоночника следует заботиться постоянно,  начиная со школьного возраста".

Предложение, действительно, оставляет желать лучшего, так как в нем нарушена и семантика, и грамматика.

Особо следует отметить следующее. Двухместные союзные соединения образуют только простые союзы ХОТЯ...НО, ХОТЯ...ТЕМ НЕ МЕНЕЕ, ПУСТЬ...ЗАТО. Для составного союза НЕСМОТРЯ НА ТО ЧТО вторая часть союза является излишней.